# Can subsets of an infinite set be a topology when the complement of these subsets are a topology

Tags: general-topology

The question is as follows:
Let $T$ be a topology on an infinite set $X$. Does the set
$T'=\{ U\subset X \;| \; X - U \in T \}$ again define a topology?

I have looked on the internet for help and could find some stuff about finite complement topologies, but couldn't really figure out this particular problem. I suspect there is some counterexample for $T'$ being a topology with the finite intersection of elements of $T'$ not being in $T'$ anymore, but couldn't find one myself.

Comment: You are pretty close, but the intersection would be fine (it corresponds to the union in the complement). Note that $T'$ contains exactly the sets that would be _closed_ in the topology $T$. So really you're asking: are there topologies where a union of infinitely many _closed_ sets isn't necessarily closed. Can you think of any? What kind of standard examples of topological spaces do you know?

Comment: We have just had our first lecture on Topology, only having worked with open sets (I do know about closed sets because of real analysis) and have learned about metric spaces being topological spaces. Thinking about it the way you said though, I think something like (-Infinity, n/(n+1)) should work over the real numbers, as its infinite union equals (-Infinity, 1), which is open.

Comment: "Being open" is not necessarily the same as "not being closed". Also, you need to invent some notation to distinguish open intervals from closed intervals; using $(...)$ for both is hardly a good idea.

Comment: oops, typo. The first one should've been a "]" instead of a ")", and you're absolutely right. It should've been "not closed" in stead of "open". Thanks!

Comment: Now your example is fine.

Comment: Great, thank you.